# How to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: python

I have this structure:

```
example.com
— bin
— include
— lib
— local
— project
    |— manage.py
    |— project
         |— __init__.py
         |— settings.py
         |— urls.py
         |— wsgi.py
```

I set `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings` and trying to install mongodb with the following command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

After execution, the following error occurs:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine to /tmp/pip-Gv3V7O-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
    ERROR:root:Error while trying to get django settings module.
    Error was: Could not import settings 'project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named project.settings

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangotoolbox>=1.6.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-mongodb-engine==0.5.2)
Cleaning up...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: My server configuration: Nginx, Uwsgi, Virtualenv and Django on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: 1) I don't see `setup.py` anywhere so it looks like your `project` is not in any `sys.path` folder 2) don't use Mongo :p

Comment: So, what I have to do?

Comment: 1) create setup.py and install your project with it so it will be registered in PYTHONPATH (eg. `python setup.py install` or `pip install -e .`) 2) use Postgres, it's much better database and a better JSON database.